# How to install specific versions of the dependencies of a local package.

Tags: r, r-package

I am creating a local R package. To ensure backward compatibility, I wish to specify versions of the dependent packages, so that when my package is being installed, the required versions of the packages that I am using in my package will be automatically be installed as well.

May I ask is there a way to do that in a R local package?

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/packrat

Comment: You can try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/versions/index.html

However, the polite way is to update your package with every new release of CRAN.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out Hadley Wickham's [tutorial](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/) on package development. Depending on how you are creating your package (hopefully you're using `devtools`), you just have to add the specific package versions to your DESCRIPTION. See below for an example DESCRIPTION file.

```
    Package: mypackage
    What The Package Does (one line, title case required)
    Version: 0.1
    Authors@R: person("First", "Last", email = "first.last@example.com",
              role = c("aut", "cre"))
    Description: What the package does (one paragraph)
    Depends: R (>= 3.1.0)
    License: What license is it under?
    LazyData: true
    Imports:
        ggvis (>= 0.2),
        dplyr (>= 0.3.0.1)
```